# can you explain why it is like this? foreach argument can still be accessed

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

```
<tbody>
    @foreach ($data as $d) 
    <tr>
    <td>{{$d->id}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
@dd($d)
```

dd still can access variable $d

Answer (score 0):

After the loop is over, the last record remains in the memory and therefore when you do `dd($d)` it prints the **ONLY** the last record.

Answer (score 0):

$d is still stored in PHP. As the last record is overwritten on the loop.

To remove $d simply

```
{{ unset($d) }}
```